# FacebookSDK Cross Domain Receiver Problem

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi can somebody help me.  I can't get rid of this error message in Chrome 9.0 beta, Chrome 8.0 or Firefox 3.6.13:

*"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL 'http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/' from frame with URL 'http://myapp.dyndns-office.com/'. Domains, protocols and ports must match."*

I'm using the FacebookSDK version 4.1.1 CSMvcFacebookApp in the Samples folder.

I have this script in my Site.Master page located in Views/Shared:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        FB_RequireFeatures(['CanvasUtil'], function () {
            FB.XdComm.Server.init("<%= ResolveUrl("~/xd_receiver.htm") %>");
            FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have xd_receiver.htm in my root directory, and presumed that the above javascript code was all I needed to do verify my domain with facebook.
Is my presumption correct or has things changed?
I even tried moving the FB code out of the JQuery ready function like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(['CanvasUtil'], function () {
        FB.XdComm.Server.init("<%= ResolveUrl("~/xd_receiver.htm") %>");
        FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent();
    });
</script>
```

But this doesn't work either ...
Can anybody shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong or how I get xd file to work using the SDK/MVC IFrame solution...

FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent() is firing because I don't have the scroll bars appear in my application, so that proves that FB_RequireFeatures function is working.  But as to whether FB.XdComm.Server.init is doing it's part I'm just not sure as to how I go about testing this ???

The content of my xd_receiver.html file in my root directory is:

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>cross domain receiver page</title>
</head>
<body>
        <!--
                As described in: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Cross-domain_communication_channel
        -->
    <script src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

XdCommReceiver.js exists as I just copied the pasted the url into the browser.  Are my paths correct or have facebook up and change the url's etc ... ?

I understand that my main concern here is that Safari won't run my app at all if I don't get this cross domain stuff sorted out now.

Any help here would be much appreciated :-\

Thanks
Rob

<< ADDITIONAL COMMENT >>

Is there a built in mechanism in the latest version of the FacebookSDK v 4.1.1 to make this cross domain stuff just work? Did the developers of the SDK think about this issue? Or have I just brought up a future feature ... :-\

Comment: This thing works, you seriously didn't have to test it out with gibberish text before editing your question in. You are just two flags away from this question being zapped to oblivion and yourself gaining the attention of the moderators.

Comment: Sorry BoltClock I did have to enter gobbldie gook because Stackoverflow wasn't playing nice, I was arm wrestling with it to get it to post my question???

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but that was a really stupid thing to do - 4 flags means it's almost auto-deleted because of spam flags, and a -4 score means it won't show up on the homepage any more, even if you edit it, so the chances of this clearly legitimate question been answered is quite small. I'll flag this for the moderators to see if they can do anything about it.

Comment: Well, how else am I suppose to post a question Yi Jiang?  Via Contact Us???  Obviously it's a software problem not a human one, don't blame me blame the developers of stackoverflow ... sheesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code you need to have in your cross-domain scripting channel file:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script></body></html>
```

Here's the code to initialize the FB Javascript SDK. Put this at the very end of your HTML files, substituting in the appropriate values and URLs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">FB.init({appId: '1234567890', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true,channelUrl: 'http://example.com/xss_channel.htm'});</script>
```

Optionally, put this in your web.config where the XSS channel file is located. This lets browsers cache the file indefinitely as recommended by Facebook.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
      <location path="xss_channel.htm">
          <system.webServer>
              <httpProtocol>
                  <customHeaders>
                      <add name="Expires" value="Tue, 01 Jan 2030 16:00:00 GMT" />
                  </customHeaders>
              </httpProtocol>
          </system.webServer>
      </location>
  </configuration>
```

And finally, if you're using XFBML, place this namespace definition in your `<html>` to make XFBML work in IE:
`xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old Facebook Connect Javascript. The Facebook C# SDK is not compatible with the old Javascript SDK. You should use the new Facebook Javascript SDK (as was included in the sample). http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/